# No permissions writing to file

Tags: c#

I know there's lots of answers relating to this question but I've not come across a solution yet.

This is a WPF application, which runs from my desktop and I am the only user of this computer.

I've tried saving to desktop, TEMP, C:, `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)`

But none of the directories I've tried is working, so I'm a bit lost/confused.

```
FileStream file = new FileStream("C:\\Users\\<username>\\AppData\\Local\\Temp",FileMode.OpenOrCreate, 
                  FileAccess.Write, 
                  FileShare.ReadWrite);

StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter(file);
sr.WriteLine(data);

sr.Close();
```

Edit:

Code error, sorry, I figured it now:

```
StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter("C:\\Users\\Mike\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\test.txt");
sr.WriteLine(data);
sr.Close();
```

Comment: Sorry, my crystal ball is in for repairs. Can you clarify "nothing is working"?

Comment: @mdm - I don't know which directory I should be using to write a file, as none of the directories I've tried works.

Comment: you're tring to create file called Temp in Local directory?? is it intentional?

Comment: @Mike: You keep saying that something isn't working, but you haven't yet told us what kind out output you are getting. If you went to a doctor because you were feeling ill, would you just tell him that you were feeling ill, or would you give him a detailed run down of your symptoms? Which do you think would lead to a successful diagnosis?

Answer (score 1):

If you need some file saved on the user PC for your application the best option is to do this in the AppData folder. This is where all programs shoud write their temp files(no matter that not evryone use it) you can access it by typing in %appdata% in your start menu run line and like this:

```
Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData
```

in your c# application. Hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

There is an high probability that your Local folder contains a folder named 'TEMP'. This will fail with your new FileStream. Moreover you should set a real user name in place to the 'username', but this is probably only a text copied from elsewhere.

However try in this way

```
string destPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
string destFile = Path.Combine(destPath, "myTempFile.txt");
FileStream file = new FileStream(destFile,FileMode.OpenOrCreate,FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Write your file like this**

```
//this is what you want to write
    string whatiWantToWrite = "Hello, i am a noob!";
       //This is how you write your file 
                    System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\\path\\to\\Desktop\\myfile.txt");
                    file.WriteLine(whatiWantToWrite);
                    file.Close();
```